# Problems with Card Flip CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flip

I have the following code working for flipping the card. But on the back of the card I have a form, and the left half of it isn't clickable. I searched online but no one seemed to have faced this problem like I did.
Did I do something wrong or is it a problem with my browser? (Google Chrome 68.0.3440.106 64 bits)

```js
var card = document.querySelector('.card');
var btncontato = document.querySelector('.btncontato');
var btncontato2 = document.querySelector('.btncontato2');
btncontato.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
btncontato2.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
```

```css
.scene {
    width: 343px;
    height: 430px;
    margin: 40px 0;
    perspective: 600px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center right;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.card__face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
    background: #eee;
    cursor: default;
}

.card__face--back {    
    background-color: #eee;
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    cursor: default;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.btn-whats, .btn-whats:active, .btn-whats:focus, .btn-whats:hover {
 background-color: #34af23;
 text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #34af23;
    padding: 8px 70px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.528571429;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-whats:hover {
 color: #34af23;
 background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card__face card__face--front">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btncontato">Contatar o corretor</button>
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<?php echo $config_Footer_WhatsApp?>" target="_blank" class="btn-whats"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> Contatar via WhatsApp</a>    
   </div>
     </div>
     <div class="card__face card__face--back">
      <div class="widget formularios-ficha">
       <button type="button" class="btn btncontato2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button> Mais <span>Informações</span> 
       <form method="POST" action="<?= URL_ABSOLUTA.'modulos/email_sender.php'?>">
         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="formName" value="f_mi_imovel" >
         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="txtAssunto" value="[SITE] Nova Mensagem recebida - FICHA DE IMOVEL REF. <?=$imovel->getID()?>" >
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                   <span class='help' style='display:none'>Como você se chama? *Obrigatório</span>
                   <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="txtNome" placeholder="Seu Nome"  > </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                 <span class='help' style='display:none'>Qual seu telefone? *Obrigatório</span>
                 <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="txtTelefone" id="" placeholder="Telefone"   > </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                 <span class='help' style='display:none'>Seu e-mail? *Obrigatório </span>
                 <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Seu Email"   >
             </div>
         </div>
         <?php if(FORM_AGENDAVISITA && $h==2){?>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:5px">
                  <div style="font-size:12px">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" id="ver-form-calendar" onclick="$('#form-calendar').toggle('slow')"> &nbsp;<b><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Quero visitar este imóvel!</b>
                  </div>
                  <div id="form-calendar" style="display: none ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtdatahora" name="txtdatahora" placeholder="Data/Hora para Visitar este imóvel"  >
                    <div class="alert alert-info" style="font-size:10px; padding:8px; line-height:14px;" role="alert"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Importante: Data/Hora de visita é uma informação sugestiva. A imobiliária irá retornar confirmando disponibilidade para esta data.</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
         <?php } ?>
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <span class='help' style='display:none'>Suas dúvidas e comentários.</span>
             <textarea class="form-control" required name="txtComentario"><?=$debug_Comentario?>Gostaria de mais informações sobre o imóvel código <?=$imovel->getID()?>.</textarea>
           </div>
         </div>

         <?php if( GOOGLE_CAPTCHA != "" ){?>
         <div class='form-group'>
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo GOOGLE_CAPTCHA?>" style="margin-top:-70px;margin-bottom: -110px;" ></div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <? } ?>

         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="margin-top:80px"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> ENVIAR</button>
           </div>
         </div>


       </form>
      </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me. Everything is clickable. Running the same version of Chrome.

Comment: yep all good there is that small button there to flip it back

Comment: Yes, working for me too, the button on the back of the card is though very small :)